# Passing a Swift variable from one IBAction to another

Tags: ios, swift, variables

In my application I have a "Play" button which creates two random numbers and creates a string for those numbers, which is then used to fill in the two `UIImage` holders for cards (cards 0-10 which are set in a Array). Then the two random numbers are added together.

There is an input field where the user can input their guess and then hit "Submit". If their answer is correct it will flash "Correct". If the answer is wrong, it will flash Try Again. My question is how can I get the total variable passed to the Submit so I can successfully create my if else statements?

So here is the end code to the Play button Action which works perfectly

```
let total = firstRandomNumber + secondRandomNumber
```

Here is the code for the Submit button which is giving me an error

```
@IBAction func submit(sender: UIButton) {
    correct.hidden = (true)
    tryagain.hidden = (true)

    let guess = Double(text.text!)

    if guess = total {
        correct.hidden = (false)

}
```

The error I'm getting is "undefined variable total"

Comment: Beware of the difference between `=` and `==`. Verify that you're really using the one that does what you intend to.

Comment: what is text.text!
Have you named referance to your textview at text? Recommend you to change that to something else if so. And please mention the error messege.

Comment: where is total declared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the variables are not going to be `PASSED` to `Submit()` because that's the function the button calls. The button can careless about your two variables. Instead you'll want to have two Global variables (in this case the two random numbers) and request them in Submit. These are variables that was created outside any functions and are set when they need to be set. So lets see how you'd do that with your code:

```
// Two random numbers (global)
var a: Int?
var b: Int?

func generateRandomNumber() {
    a = // assign a to the number generator value
    b = // same as above
}

func submit() { // your button call
    if let userGuess = text.text { // do if let instead of ! it's safer
        let total = a + b

        if userGuess == total { // our check remember == is different from = 
            correctView.hidden = false
        } else { // if it's wrong show this view
            tryAgainView.hidden = false
        } 
    }
}
```

Obviously there's a bunch missing but you can get the main idea. Let me know if these anything I can answer about this method.

Comment: Thank you John, I wasn't sure if I could pass the variable or not between to actions. I'll play with it tonight and see if it works with the randomization done globally.